# Make statement more clear: checking object for key in dictionary

Tags: swift

I have dictionary of type - `[String : [MyClass]]`.

I have array of type `MyClass`, what i want is to check, whether my dictionary contain array of `MyClass` object for specific key. If it does, it append element to array, if not, it create new array with single element `MyClass`. I ended up with:

```
for item in items{
    if let _ = dict[key] {
        // Add operations if corresponding array exist
        dict[key]?.append(item)         
    } else {
        // Create array if need
        dict[key] = [item]
   }
}
```

it work but look kind of ugly, and i use optional binding for check whether array exist, but not use the result (wildcard pattern _).

Is there anyway to make that code look shorter and cleaner? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this inside a loop?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri because i need to modify collection over iterating of collection of [MyClass] items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can test *and* get an existing value with optional binding,
and then append (or set) all new items:

```
if let oldItems = dict[key] {
    dict[key] = oldItems + items
} else {
    dict[key] = items
}
```

This can be simplified with the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? []) + items
```

In **Swift 4** you can simply use the [subscript method with a default value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript):

```
dict[key, default: []] += items
// Or:
dict[key, default: []].append(contentsOf: items)
```

Self-contained example:

```
var dict = ["foo": [1, 2, 3]]

dict["foo", default: []] += [4, 5]
dict["bar", default: []] += [6,7]

print(dict) // ["bar": [6, 7], "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: thanks! Code - dict["bar", default: []] += [6,7] is mean - check value for key "bar" in dictionary dict, and if it's not exist create empty array? I understand correct?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: First the subscript getter returns the value (if it exists) or an empty array. Then the new items are appended. Finally the subscript setter  sets the new value in the dictionary.

Comment: i tried your solution in my code but it says - myClass does not conform to protocol sequence. I ended with : groupedOperationsDict[shiftName, default: []].append(item)

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: What I meant is that you can append the *entire array* in one step with `append(contentsOf: items)` – no for-loop needed. Alternatively append single items with `append(item)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following implementation to avoid wildCart pattern :

```
import Foundation

class MyClass { }
class Apple : MyClass { }
class Ant : MyClass { }
class Ambulance : MyClass { }

class Test {

 var dictionary : [String : [MyClass.Type]] = [:]
 let items : [MyClass.Type] = [Apple.self, Ant.self, Ambulance.self]
 let key = "a"

 public func insert(key : String, items : [MyClass.Type] ) {
    guard !items.isEmpty else { return }

    items.forEach { (item) in
        if dictionary[key] == nil {
            dictionary[key] = [item]
        } else {
            dictionary[key]?.append(item)
        }
    }
 }

}

let test = Test()
test.insert(key: test.key, items: test.items)
print(test.dictionary)
```

#### Output :

```
["a": [__lldb_expr_27.Apple, __lldb_expr_27.Ant, __lldb_expr_27.Ambulance]]
```